# How to assign value to obs in flutter getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

The below code working fine so far,

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
  var count = 0.obs;
  increment() => count++;
}
```

But when I assign a value it doesn't work as expected not event with type cast.

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
  var count = 0.obs;
  reset() => count = 10;
}
```

I would like to know how to assign value ( with '=' ) in get x obs objects?

Comment: simply do ```count.value = 10;```

Comment: You can set count directly as well: ```count(10)```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This answer has been changed after I have been notified that I was wrong. I want to say thanks to Ivo Beckers to pointing put my misunderstanding of how `RxInt` works. Please upvote his answer.*

`0.obs` returns the type `RxInt`. When you call `++` on this object, it is calling the `+` operator on the `RxInt` object with `1` to increment the value. It should be noted that the `+` and `-` operators for `RxInt` does manipulate the object itself and does therefore not behave like e.g. `int` which is immutable and does therefore require the return of a new object from the operation.

When you do `count = 10` you are actually saying you want `count` to be overwritten with `10` which are of the type `int` and not `RxInt`.

What you want is more likely to be the following to you can report back to any subscribers that the value have been reset to `10`:

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
  var count = 0.obs;
  reset() => count.value = 10;
}
```

Comment: Does this really work? I would expect that creating a new object and assigning it wouldn't notify any observers because they refer to the old object or not? I expect that OP actually would want `reset() => count.value = 10;`. Or does that result in the same behaviour?

Comment: And you're wrong about the `+` operator creating a new `RxInt` instance. RxInt specifically defines the `+` operator as increasing the existing `RxInt`'s value

Comment: @IvoBeckers I don't really know anything about `RxInt` but could just see where the problem might have been. I did however expect `RxInt` to behave similar as `int` and therefore be immutable but I can clearly see I was wrong about that assumption after checking the code (what a horrible design choice of letting `-` and `+` manipulate the object itself and return itself...). So you are totally right in that the `reset()` method is not what we want.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I have changed my answer and hope it is actually correct now. Please tell me if there are any misunderstanding. :)

Comment: yeah it looks good now

Answer (score 3):

To set the value of an `RxInt` you simple assign it to the value. So you do

```
reset() => count.value = 10;
```

The reason why ++ also works is because `count++` simply translates to `count = count + 1` and this calls the operator on the `RxInt` instance which simply increases its value as you can see in the implementation of `RxInt`:

```
class RxInt extends Rx<int> {
  RxInt(int initial) : super(initial);

  /// Addition operator.
  RxInt operator +(int other) {
    value = value + other;
    return this;
  }

  /// Subtraction operator.
  RxInt operator -(int other) {
    value = value - other;
    return this;
  }
}
```